# re reading a csv file in python without loading it again

Tags: python, file, csv, seek

I made the following code which works but I want to improve it. I don't want to re-read the file, but if I delete sales_input.seek(0) it won't iterate throw each row in sales. How can i improve this?

```
def computeCritics(mode, cleaned_sales_input = "data/cleaned_sales.csv"):
    if mode == 1:
        print "creating customer.critics.recommendations"
        critics_output = open("data/customer/customer.critics.recommendations", 
                              "wb")
        ID = getCustomerSet(cleaned_sales_input)
        sales_dict = pickle.load(open("data/customer/books.dict.recommendations", 
                                      "r"))
    else: 
        print "creating books.critics.recommendations"
        critics_output = open("data/books/books.critics.recommendations", 
                              "wb")
        ID = getBookSet(cleaned_sales_input)
        sales_dict = pickle.load(open("data/books/users.dict.recommendations", 
                                      "r"))
    critics = {}
    # make critics dict and pickle it 
    for i in ID:
        with open(cleaned_sales_input, 'rb') as sales_input:
            sales = csv.reader(sales_input)  # read new 
            for j in sales:
                if mode == 1:
                    if int(i) == int(j[2]):
                        sales_dict[int(j[6])] = 1
                else: 
                    if int(i) == int(j[6]):
                        sales_dict[int(j[2])] = 1
            critics[int(i)] = sales_dict
    pickle.dump(critics, critics_output)
    print "done"
```

cleaned_sales_input looks like

```
6042772,2723,3546414,9782072488887,1,9.99,314968
6042769,2723,3546414,9782072488887,1,9.99,314968
...
```

where number 6 is the book ID and number 0 is the customer ID

I want to get a dict wich looks like

```
critics = {
    CustomerID1: {
        BookID1: 1,
        BookID2: 0,
        ........
        BookIDX: 0
    },
    CustomerID2: {
        BookID1: 0,
        BookID2: 1,
        ...
    }
}
```

or

```
critics = {
    BookID1: {
        CustomerID1: 1,
        CustomerID2: 0,
        ........
        CustomerIDX: 0
    },
    BookID1: {
        CustomerID1: 0,
        CustomerID2: 1,
        ...
        CustomerIDX: 0
    }
}
```

I hope this isn't to much information

Comment: Did you profile this to see if csv reading is the bottleneck?

Comment: sorry but what is this profile? i never heard of that.

Comment: A [profiler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) is used to see how much time is spend on each part of your code. You do this to identify bottlenecks in your code. Optimizing things before you profile is (nearly) useless because you don't know what the bottleneck is. So maybe your filereading is not the bottleneck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

Let's first look at this code pattern:

```
for i in ID:
    for j in sales:
        if int(i) == int(j[2])
```

notice that `i` is only being compared with `j[2]`. That's its only purpose in the loop. `int(i) == int(j[2])` can only be True at most once for each `i`.

So, we can completely remove the `for i in ID` loop by rewriting it as

```
for j in sales:
    key = j[2]
    if key in ID:
```

Based on the function names `getCustomerSet` and `getBookSet`, it sounds as if
`ID` is a set (as opposed to a list or tuple). We want ID to be a set since
testing membership in a set is O(1) (as opposed to O(n) for a list or tuple).

---

Next, consider this line:

```
critics[int(i)] = sales_dict
```

There is a potential pitfall here. This line is assigning `sales_dict` to
`critics[int(i)]` for each `i` in `ID`. Each key `int(i)` is being mapped to the very same `dict`. As we loop through `sales` and `ID`, we are modifying `sales_dict` like this, for example:

```
sales_dict[int(j[6])] = 1
```

But this will cause **all** values in `critics` to be modified simultaneously, since all keys in `critics` point to the same dict, `sales_dict`. I doubt that is what you want.

To avoid this pitfall, we need to make copies of the sales_dict:

```
critics = {i:sales_dict.copy() for i in ID}
```

---

```
def computeCritics(mode, cleaned_sales_input="data/cleaned_sales.csv"):
    if mode == 1:
        filename = 'customer.critics.recommendations'
        path = os.path.join("data/customer", filename)
        ID = getCustomerSet(cleaned_sales_input)
        sales_dict = pickle.load(
            open("data/customer/books.dict.recommendations", "r"))
        key_idx, other_idx = 2, 6
    else:
        filename = 'books.critics.recommendations'
        path = os.path.join("data/books", filename)        
        ID = getBookSet(cleaned_sales_input)
        sales_dict = pickle.load(
            open("data/books/users.dict.recommendations", "r"))
        key_idx, other_idx = 6, 2

    print "creating {}".format(filename)
    ID = {int(item) for item in ID}
    critics = {i:sales_dict.copy() for i in ID}
    with open(path, "wb") as critics_output:
        # make critics dict and pickle it
        with open(cleaned_sales_input, 'rb') as sales_input:
            sales = csv.reader(sales_input)  # read new
            for j in sales:
                key = int(j[key_idx])
                if key in ID:
                    other_key = int(j[other_idx])
                    critics[key][other_key] = 1                    
                critics[key] = sales_dict
        pickle.dump(dict(critics), critics_output)
        print "done"
```

Comment: Sorry for not adding it but i want to make da dict which looks like c = { ID1 { Book : 1 , Book: 0 ........ Book:0 } , ID2 .....} so i must go this way or am i just blockeahed?

Comment: There is no obvious relationship between your code and the dict. You need to fill in more details like what does `ID` equal and a sample of `cleaned_sales_input` before your question can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

@unutbu's answer is better but if you are stuck with this structure you can put the whole file in memory:

```
sales = []
with open(cleaned_sales_input, 'rb') as sales_input:
     sales_reader = csv.reader(sales_input)       
     [sales.append(line) for line in sales_reader]

     for i in ID:
        for j in sales:
            #do stuff
```